# Angular Jasmine spyOn query call

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm very new to Angular and Jasmine, and I'm having issues when I'm trying to fake a service "query" call.  The following is surrounded by a "describe":

```
var mockBackend;

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, AppServ) {
  // We need to setup our controllers to use fake services provided by angular-mocks
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  mockBackend = AppServ;

  $controller('AppInformationController', {
    $scope: $scope,
    AppServ: mockBackend
  });
}));

it("should try to call the service, but we intercept it", function() {
  spyOn(mockBackend, 'query').andReturn({'title':'Mock title'});

  $scope.serverAppNameChange();
  expect($scope.app.title).toBe("Mock title");
});
```

Above "AppServ" is my service, and I would like to intercept whenever the test calls "query" on that service to return some default information.  Really this is just to get the idea of how Jasmine and Angular work.  The service itself does nothing but hold on to a local copy (it's basically a fake service).

Here is the service:

```
Services.factory("AppServ", function($http) {
  var app = {};
  var theAppOnServer = {};

  app['query'] = function() {
    return theAppOnServer;
  };

  app['save'] = function(app) {
    theAppOnServer = $.extend({}, app);
  };

  app['updateApp'] = function() {
    theAppOnServer['title'] = "Title From Server";
  };

  return app;
});
```

Here is the controller:

```
MobileIntake.controller("AppInformationController", function($scope, AppServ) {
  $scope.app = AppServ.query();

  //var AppOverviewController = function($scope) {
  $scope.appNameChange = function(oldValue, newValue, scope) {
    console.log("You've changed the app name!");
  };

  $scope.serverAppNameChange = function() {
    AppServ.updateApp();
  };
  // Set up a watcher if we want to be updated by other things (like the server)
  $scope.$watch("app.title", $scope.appNameChange);

});
```

Could someone please clue me in as to why the spyOn doesn't seem to be intercepting the "query" function call on the service?  I've seen a couple other answers and they are using $http and some special logic with that, but I just want to get the idea that I can intercept non-http functions as well.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the extra `mockBackend` object. Just spy on the service itself.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
  // We need to setup our controllers to use fake services provided by angular-mocks
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();

  $controller('AppInformationController', {
    $scope: $scope
  });
}));

it("should try to call the service, but we intercept it", inject(function(AppServ) {
  spyOn(AppServ, 'query').andReturn({'title':'Mock title'});

  $scope.serverAppNameChange();
  expect($scope.app.title).toBe("Mock title");
}));
```

Comment: I get "AppServ" is not defined.  My "AppInformationController" needs the AppServ injected, and to get that wouldn't I need to still have it in the "inject(function($rootScope,$controller, AppServ))" portion?

Comment: Where do you get AppServ being undefined? You added `inject` to your `it` right? When setting up the controller for your tests, you don't need to give the `$controller` service all your dependencies. In angular's phonecat app (https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat), they have a controller that injects a `Phone` resource (https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/app/js/controllers.js), yet in the test (https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/test/unit/controllersSpec.js#L18), they don't pass it into `$controller`.

Comment: In the PhoneCat example, the test uses `ctrl = $controller(PhoneListCtrl, {$scope: scope});` As you can see the "PhoneListCtrl" is a variable in the global scope, not built in the .controller like my example is.  I've had better experience using the global variables instead of the module.controller type notation for tests, but it should be able to be tested either way.

Comment: Right, my point is that you don't have to pass in your dependencies into the `$controller` service. I have a controller that is registered via `module.controller` with a bunch of injected dependencies, and in my tests I only do `$controller("MyController", {$scope: scope});`. Then I spy the services as needed in the `it`s and it all works. If you're getting `undefined` for `AppServ` when trying to inject it into your it, it makes me think it's not being registered right.

Comment: I'm no longer using AngularJS, so I am unable to test to see if this works.